# Como regresar en ruby on rails un objecto con un arreglo de ids de una relacion has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

espero que puedan ayudarme, tengo los siguientes modelos

```
class Family < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :families
end
```

y necesito regresar un objeto como el siguiente

```
{
 id: 1
 descripcion: 'Ejemplo',
 categories: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

en donde el objeto principal pertenece a Family, lo intente con include pero me retorna un arreglo de objectos Category y no es lo que necesito, lo que necesito es el arreglo de ids, he buscado y no encontre nada espero que alguien sepa como hacerlo por favor

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el método `as_json` directamente sobre el resultado de tu modelo, junto con los parámetros `include` y `except`; por ejemplo:

```
Family.first.as_json(include: :categories, except: :created_at, :updated_at)
```

Resultado:

```
{
  id: 1
  descripcion: 'Ejemplo',
  categories: [
    { id: 1, descripcion: "category 1", created_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00", updated_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00" },
    { id: 2, descripcion: "category 2", created_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00", updated_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00"  },
    { id: 3, descripcion: "category 3", created_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00", updated_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00"  },
    { id: 4, descripcion: "category 4", created_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00", updated_at: "2018-01-01T00:00:00"  }
  ]
}
```

`include` indica las asociaciones que deseas incluir y `except` indican las columnas a omitir del objeto base (i.e. `Family`); con ese resultado podrías después leer sólo los `id` de cada categoría, o bien, podrías indicar que te traiga sólo el `id`:

```
Family.first.as_json(include: [categories: { only: :id }], except: :created_at, :updated_at)
```

Resultado:

```
{
  id: 1
  descripcion: 'Ejemplo',
  categories: [
    { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }
  ]
}
```

Esta es la forma más sencilla, sin embargo no podrías generar el arreglo con los `id` tal como lo especificas en tu pregunta; si necesitas esa opción, entonces te recomendaría utilizar [jBuilder](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/articles/crafting-apis-with-rails--cms-27695) o [ActiveModel Serializer](http://katade.com/2016/08/09/activemodel-serializer-jbuilder/).